# bootstrap 3 center div in CELL

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I want to center a div within a cell in the container row. when I looked I only found topics about centering the div in the container which is not what I need. I want to know how to center the div (both vertically and horizontally) in the particular cell that it is. The reason is that on the same row I have other divs of bigger height and at the end of the row I want to put a button which is relatively small compared to the other divs and hence I want to center it to make it look pretty.

What I've tried until now is to go into the bootstrap.min.css file and change the following:

```
.table>thead>tr>th,
.table>tbody>tr>th,
.table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>td{
padding:8px;
line-height:1.42857143;
vertical-align:top;
border-top:1px solid #ddd}
```

to:

```
.table>thead>tr>th,
.table>tbody>tr>th,
.table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>td{
padding:8px;
line-height:1.42857143;
vertical-align:middle;
border-top:1px solid #ddd}
```

Which didn't seem to change anything so I'm guessing I'm not on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both vertical and horizontal centering, this solution worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hg8Sn/

The only downside of this is that as I am using bootstrap, when the window gets smaller the button would be aligned to the left of the div. I fixed this by making the button take up the whole width of the div so I set col-xs and col-md to 12:

```
 <div id="addchart" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
     <button id="add-chart-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Add Chart</button>
 </div>
```

For me, this only centers the button and it doesn't stretch it to the width of the container. It could be because I am using a specific bootstrap theme but either way if someone would want to fix this then they can set a fixed width to the button.

Comment: but i suggested the same thing to you yesterday except that it was an attribute instead of a CSS property. it didnt work for me as well though. i will try your solution. thank you!

Comment: To be honest even my solution is not very good because the line-height still takes some fixed value. I'm going to try and see if I can change the bootstrap.min.css file in order to center the elements in the cell itself.

Comment: just edit bootstrap.css and use less to make it like bootstrap.min.css. it is hard to edit bootstrap.min.css as it is compressed.

Comment: good idea! but would need to find out *what* I need to edit first! :)

Answer (score 2):

For center-ing a div horizontally, you can put in CSS file:

```
margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;
```

For vertical alignment:

```
margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;
```

Posting your HTML code would be helpful btw.

Comment: What I put in my CSS: 
#add-chart {
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top: auto; 
        margin-bottom: auto;
    }

The div containing the button:

<div id="add-chart" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6  col-sm-6" >
                    <button id="add-chart-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Add Chart</button>
                </div>

If this is what you are suggesting, it didn't change anything for me.

Comment: Are you trying to put that button in the center of the cell?

Comment: For centering horizontally the contents in a specific cell you just add align like <td align="center" /> 
For vertical, 
<td class="vert-align"></td> (This one is specifically for Bootstrap)

Comment: Could you show me where I need to use this, please?

Comment: In your HTML code, the specific cell you are trying to modify:
<td class="vert-align" align="center">Whatever goes inside here</td>.
I cannot help you much until you post your table code in your original question!

Comment: If I could post it I would. It contains confidential information and I've provided the div for my button so I don't see why you would need the rest.

Comment: I am currently working on finding the answer for this. I apologize I forgot you were using Bootstrap grids. You can center horizontally by adding text-center class to your div. So, <div id="add-chart" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 text-center" > <button id="add-chart-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Add Chart</button> </div>. I will get back to you on the vertical part!

Comment: For vertical try this link: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/
I've used it before it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, text-center would position it in the middle (horizontally). With regards to the vertical centering, I didn't like any of those solutions but I came across one today that did the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/hg8Sn/. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score -2):

Check and see you are using bootstrap.min.css and not bootstrap.css.
Maybe you might be linking the wrong css files.

Comment: How is that any different? bootstrap.min.css is the same as bootstrap.css except that it is compressed by getting rid of all the white spaces and making file size smaller.

Comment: as in he might be only referencing bootstrap.css but editing bootstrap.min.css thus explaining all the editing he done but no result shown.